# JavaScript - Incorrect division

Tags: javascript, math

```
 perc = 15/30;
 //result=Math.round(perc*100)/100  //returns 28.45
 $('#counter').text(perc);
 $('#total').text(count);
```

returns back `0.5%` which is suppose to be `50.00%`... how do I fix this? :S

Comment: Multiply by 100. I'm not going to post this as an answer, because this is too… strange.

Comment: @Tomalak Because those low rep users have to get their reps from *somewhere* :)

Comment: How can `((15/30)*100)/100` return `28.45`?

Comment: @Álvaro: It doesn't, that's why it is commented out. :-D

Comment: `15/30` is a fraction, not a percentage.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You do realize that word **percent** quite literally translates into "per cent" or "per 100" since **cent** is the latin root that's used everywhere meaning "100" or "one-hundredth".

- Century (100 years)
- US Cent (100th of a dollar)
- Centurion (Those who commanded 100 soldiers)
- Centipede (creature with 100 legs)

So **50%** becomes **50 per cent** becomes **50 per 100**

And, since in mathematical terms, the word **per** means **divide** (miles per hour == mph == m/h) then we can distill **50%** down to:

> 50/100

Which, surprisingly enough, is represented as the decimal number **.5**

Answer (score 11):

15/30 = 0.5

if you want to have percent number you have to multiply it by 100.

Answer (score 7):

I am a low rep user so here goes.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage

Treat the % sign as a constant equal to 0.01.  Thus, when working with a number like `50%`, treat it as `50 * 0.01` or `0.5`.

```
0.5 = n %                  // I want to know what 0.5 is as a percent
0.5 / % = n * % / %        // Divide both sides by the constant
0.5 / % = n                // Remove the excess
0.5 / 0.01 = n             // Replace the constant
50 = n                     // You have your answer
```

Answer (score 5):

Just multiply by 100.

Comment: i like this answer... it's so simple and straight forward :p